# 'When the rising rate cycle gives way to a decline in borrowing costs, bond funds will ...'?

Tags: interest-rate, bond-funds

> [[Source:]](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/investment-ideas/bonds-bond-etfs-bond-funds-which-is-best-for-you/article11874369/) Bonds fall in value when rates rise, and this will be reflected in the unit price of bond funds. **When the rising rate cycle *gives way to* a decline in borrowing costs,** bond funds will rise in price.
>
> ***[give way to](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/give-way?q=give+way+to#give-way__2) =*** Allow oneself to be overcome by, or to succumb to (an emotion or impulse):

What does the bolded mean? Substitute the definition of ***give way to***:

> **When the rising rate cycle succumbs to a decline in borrowing costs,** `bond funds will rise in price`.

But then why does **a decline in borrowing costs** imply that the grey?
Does **a decline in borrowing costs** somehow relate to an increase in interest rates?

Answer (score 2):

Although people anthropomorphize the financial markets, they do not really have emotions. Use definition 2 instead: `Be replaced or superseded by:` Also 'borrowing costs' is usually just interest, which (for any given principal) is higher when the interest rate is higher. Thus:

- When market interest rate goes up, bond values go down. Since bond funds hold bonds as assets, those fund values also go down.
- When interest rate goes down, bond/fund values go up.
- When interest rate *was* going up and *changes* to going down, values *start* going up.

Their point is that a fund (traditional or ETF) always trades at valuation (NAV or market price arbitraged toward NAV) which varies in this way -- plus or minus transaction costs, but they are ignored here -- while an individual bond varies if traded *now* but if held to (near) *maturity* it converges to its face value (unless defaulted).